# Projection map on a product topology

Tags: general-topology, functions, elementary-set-theory

I have a quick question.

Say the set $X\times Y$ is equipped with a product topology $\mathcal{T}$.

And let $p : X\times Y \to X$ be the projection map $(x,y) \mapsto x$.

Now consider an open set $\mathcal{U}$  in the topology of $X$.I'm trying to figure out what $p^{-1}(\mathcal{U})$ is.

- Is it simply $\mathcal{U}\times Y$?
- or rather $\{\mathcal{U}\times\mathcal{V} : \mathcal{V} \text{ open in } Y\}$ ?

Comment: It's simply $U\times Y$.

Comment: Thanks @Berci, but why though? :/ Cause any set $\mathcal{U}\times\mathcal{V}$ with $\mathcal{V}$ open in $Y$ gets mapped to $X$ :/

Comment: @Arthur yes but you have to consider the biggest one. Berci's answer explains it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with topology and the answer is $U\times Y$, because\begin{align}p^{-1}(U)&=\{(x,u)\in X\times Y\,|\,p(x,y)\in U\}\\&=\{(x,u)\in X\times Y\,|\,x\in U\}\\&=U\times Y.\end{align}

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't made it to the topology part yet. I'm actually trying to prove that if $Z$ is a topological space, $p_x$ the $x-$projection and $p_y$ the $y-$ projection, and $f : Z \to X\times Y$ then : $p_x\circ f$ and $p_y\circ f$ are continuous $\implies f$ is.

Comment: So does that mean I can just say: every open set of $X\times Y$ can be written $\mathcal{U}\times\mathcal{V}$, with $\mathcal{U}$ and $\mathcal{V}$ respectively open in $X$ and $Y$. And that implies: $f^{-1}(\mathcal{U}\times\mathcal{V}) = f^{-1}(p_x^{-1}(\mathcal{U}))\cap f^{-1}(p_y^{-1}(\mathcal{V}))$ ? (Not sure about that last equality)

Comment: No. The open sets in $X\times Y$ are *unions* of products $U\times V$, where $U$ is an open subset of $X$ and $V$ is an open subset of $Y$.

Comment: Ah, fair point. I'll try and work that out. Thanks for your help, both of you :)

Answer (score 1):

By definition of the preimage of a subset in the codomain, we have
$$p^{-1}(U)=\{(x,y)\in X\times Y : p((x,y))\in U\}$$
and this set is $U\times Y$.
It's also true that for any $V\subseteq U,\, W\subseteq Y$, we get $p(V\times W)\subseteq U$, or equivalently, $V\times W\subseteq p^{-1}(U)$.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: One last question to get the hand of it though. If $p_x$ is the $x-$projection and $p_y$ the $y$ projection, say we have $A \subset X$, $B \subset Y$. Can we say $A\times B = p_x^{-1}(A)\cap p_y^{-1}(B)$? :)

Comment: Yes, indeed we have $A\times B=(A\times Y)\cap(X\times B)=p_X^{-1}(A)\cap p_Y^{-1}(B)$.

Comment: Aight, thanks :). I guess that's close enough to what I'm trying to prove. I'll try and figure it out ^^